# CLLocationManager Use of undeclared identifier 'error'

Tags: ios, objective-c

Am setting up CLLocationManager to decipher error codes, but am getting an undeclared identifier 'error' which I have commented out.

Why is Xcode asking me to declare 'error' as an identifier? I thought that CLLocationManager would read in error codes and translate them into plain English?

What am I missing here?

CurrentLocationViewController.m

```
#import "CurrentLocationViewController.h"

@interface CurrentLocationViewController ()

@end

@implementation CurrentLocationViewController {
    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
    CLLocation *_location;

    BOOL _updatingLocation;
    NSError *_lastLocationError;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self updateLabels];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)getLocation:(id)sender
{
    [self startLocationManager];
    [self updateLabels];

}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError %@", error);
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    if (error.code == kCLErrorLocationUnknown) {  // Use of undeclared identifier 'error'
        return;
    }

    [self stopLocationManager];
    _lastLocationError = error; // Use of undeclared identifier 'error'

       [self updateLabels];
}

-(void)updateLabels
{
    if (_location != nil) {
        self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", _location.coordinate.latitude];
        self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", _location.coordinate.longitude];
        self.tagButton.hidden = NO;
        self.messageLabel.text = @"";
    } else {
        self.latitudeLabel.text = @"";
        self.longitudeLabel.text = @"";
        self.addressLabel.text = @"";
        self.tagButton.hidden = YES;

        NSString *statusMessage;
        if (_lastLocationError == nil) {
            if ([_lastLocationError.domain isEqualToString:kCLErrorDomain] && _lastLocationError.code == kCLErrorDenied) {
                statusMessage = @"Location Services Disabled";
            } else {
                statusMessage = @"Error Getting Location";
            }
        } else if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            statusMessage = @"Location Services Disabled";
        } else if (_updatingLocation) {
            statusMessage = @"Searching...";
        } else {
            statusMessage = @"Press the Button to Start";
        }

        self.messageLabel.text = statusMessage;
        }
}

-(void)startLocationManager
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        _updatingLocation = YES;
    }
}

-(void)stopLocationManager
{
    if (_updatingLocation) {
        [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        _locationManager.delegate = nil;
        _updatingLocation = NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Where did you declared `error` which you used in `didUpdateLocations` method? `didUpdateLocations` method don't return any error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with either Xcode or `CLLocationManager`. Runtime != compile-time. You really need to read a good C book to get an idea about variables and declarations.

Comment: Found the problem. Wrong statements in the wrong method. Fixed it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh jeez. You're in over your head, aren't you?

It looks like you have 2 methods that deal with a variable called "error".

The first is locationManager:didFailWithError:

This method is the method the location manager will call if it detects an error state.

In that method, an NSError object is  being passed in as "error". If you want to log/save the error that you get back, this is the place to do it. You should probably save the error to _lastLocationError here if you will need it later. It would also be a good idea to display the error to the user in this method.

The second method that tries to refer to a variable called "error" is locationManager:didUpdateLocations:

That method does not have "error" as a parameter. The variable name "error" is not meaningful here. You won't get error values here, and should not expect them.

It's likely that if your locationManager:didFailWithError: method is called, your locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method will never be called because the location manager already told you that there was a problem and it was not able to handle your request.

Comment: OK, thank you. That explanation was helpful.